# Eliminating Sine

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: How is the 3.22502 derived? -0.0834301 is asin(-0.0833333), but I can't figure out where 3.22502 comes from]

How is the $3.22502$ derived? $-0.0834301$ is $\arcsin(-0.0833333)$, but I can't figure out where $3.22502$ comes from.

It's been bugging me all day!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess using the identity $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$. Instead of considering $\arcsin(-0.0833333)$, they took $\pi-\arcsin(-0.0833333)=\pi+\arcsin(0.0833333)$.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response - seems obvious now - doh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $-0.0834301 = \pi - 3.22502$

Comment: Awwwwwww - thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

3.22502 is also a arcsin of -0.083333. n1 and n2 differ by 1.